# Distributed conditional type of string literal unions

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to create a function that has two parameters which should both be of the same type. That type can be any of a list of types which themselves are a list of string literals.

```
type A = "A1" | "A2" | "A3";
type B = "B1" | "B2" | "B3";
type Union = A | B;

type params<T> = T extends Union ? {input: T, output: T} : never;
function test(params: params<Union>) {
  ...
}
```

Expected:

```
type params<Union> = {input: A, output: A} | {input: B, output: B}
```

What happens:

```
type params<Union> = {input: "A1", output: "A1"} | {input: "A2", output: "A2"} | {input: "A3", output: "A3"} | {input: "B1", output: "B1"} | {input: "B2", output: "B2"} | {input: "B3", output: "B3"}
```

Comment: `Union` is just one big union of all of the members from `A` and all of the members from `B` (that looks like `"A1" | "A2" | "A3" | "B1" | "B2" | "B3"`) — there's no division based on the construction syntax. You could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQqajw), and if that meets your needs, I can write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not pass unioned type into `params<T>` generic. Instead create type generic which accepts two separate types  - `InputOutputUnion<A, B>`:

```
type A = "A1" | "A2" | "A3";
type B = "B1" | "B2" | "B3";

type InputOutput<T> = { input: T, output: T }
type InputOutputUnion<T, U> = InputOutput<T> | InputOutput<U>
type Params = InputOutputUnion<A, B>

let params1: Params = { input: "A1", output: "A2" }    // correct
let params2: Params = { input: "B1", output: "B2" }    // correct
let params3: Params = { input: "A1", output: "B1" }    // error
```

You can also use more generic solution allowing multiple unions:

```
type InputOutputUnionN<T extends any[]> =
  | InputOutput<T[0]>
  | InputOutput<T[1]>
  | InputOutput<T[2]>
  | InputOutput<T[3]>
type Params = InputOutputUnionN<[A, B]>
```